# Is it possible to combine overflow-x with flex-wrap?

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow

I try to create a media gallery in my angular app

I would like to create a responsive gallery which respect these rules :

- every media will be 200px width
- The items will wrap inside the container
- Have a fixed media number per row before wrapping no matter the resolution of the screen

I mean having a flex container with wrap but having an overflow-x at the same time if resolution needs it

Is it possible to combine overflow-x with flex-wrap ?

Here is a codepen of my try, each item have min width of 200px and flex-basis of 25% to fit 4 in a row

```
 .wrapper {
  background: #456173;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  width:500px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow-x:auto;
}
.cards-content {
  align-items: center;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  color: #111;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 900;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  min-width:200px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/Eytan20/pen/bGxdRYv

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0):

Your Wrapper has an absolute width of 500px, thats why it is not responsive. You can use media-queries to add styling only for mobile for example and set the width to 100%.

```
/* On screens that are 600px or less, set the background color to olive */
@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```